# How can I Force desktop view on a mobile device from my HTML or JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm updating site and the mobile view isn't looking that presentable.
I tried rewriting the code, but it's still frustrating, as I wasn't the person who built the front-end

Is there any code either in the { header } or a JavaScript function that can achieve this?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended a few solutions for you

if you want to identify the device use JavaScript

```
/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

OR

```
'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)
```

But you can use css with screen width

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 560px) { .exampleclass {} }
```

Or create a custom file for the mobile version and call it in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 560px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the meta link to display a desktop version:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Instead of the responsive version which is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: why 1024?. Am curious

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things you can try -

1. In some cases, it will work. The issue with this is, it widens the mobile browser view, not exactly the desktop view.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`

2. Update the scale in meta tag. It worked for my website properly.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">`

(See, it's 0.1 instead of 1.0)